# Why is dbml generating extra classes

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

i am having a small problem here.

The table which dbml (LinqToSql designer) is using has columns (Foreign keys), for which it generates two objectsfor the coressponding Blogs table (1:1 association) in DB lmost same,

like

**Table Authors:** AuthorID INT,  Name varchar(20), BlogID INT

And

`TABLE BLOG:`  BlogID INT, Name varchar(MAX)

- Blog { string name; int ID}
- Blog1 { string name; int ID}

It appears in intellisense as well. I have even deleted and Added a new dbml, but still same results. What is going on ?

Comment: Do you have another object called Blog in another schema of the same database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time I've had that happen is when I have two FK references in the database (I have multiple columns pointing to the same table via an FK), either I did this intentionally or I had two references by accident.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

The only time I've seen L2S code generator do this is when I've had two tables with the same name but contained in different schema's. I suspect this is what is happening to you. BTW, we wrote our own code generator to deal with this, because L2S doesn't handle tables in different schema's very well.